# orderby with multiple data received from query in flutter firestore

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have 2 collections .
first collection:
Categories - with the field 'position' and the field 'name'
for example:

- pos: 1 ----- name: vegetables
- pos: 2 ----- name: fruits

The other collection are my products with include the names of the products and a field 'category' which contains the name of the categories
for example:

- name: Banana ------ category: fruits
- name: potato ------ category: vegetables

In my app the user can in reorderableListView the categorys to his needs.
Now, i try to make a query on the category collection:
for example:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('categories').orderby('pos').get();
```

so i will receive the result in the right order.

After that i want to query the products to receive them in the sortorder than the categories result.

How is that possible??

```
....orderby(?.RESULT FROM CATEGORY QUERY ?)
```

i dont know what to write inside the orderby statement???
is something like this possible? or can i build the query programmaticaly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific API that allows this type of query, so your options are:

1. Retrieve the results one by one (or in batches of up to 10 using an `IN` query on the document ID) and then re-order them in your application code.
2. Retrieve the results one by one in the right order already.

Comment: ist there another solution by changing my Database structure? I dont know exactly how to  do it as i am new in flutter programming

Comment: You could duplicate the necessary information into each product that belongs to that category, which is known as denormalizing and is quite common in NoSQL databases. To learn more about this and many other considerations, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching Todd's excellent [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)

Comment: My problem ist that i have more than 3000 products in my DB. If a customer changes the sortorder with the reordable listviee, this will affect to all the products in my DB and will cost alot of reads.....is it possible that i put the informations in the parent document of the subcollection and read all together @frank van Puffelen ??

Comment: I don't see any subcollection in the question, but if you have that you can indeed put *some* aggregate/derived information in the parent document - as long as you stay within the 1MB size limit of a document.